# Jmeter command line set heap size

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am trying to set jmeter heap size using following command. Could you help me to resolve the mistake am making here?

set HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m" && "C:\jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\script1.jmx -e -o C:\folder1\folder2\folder3"

It gives me the following error.
***** is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

All i need is to set heap size during my non gui execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making several:

1. You need to provide the path to the .[jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) via `-l` command-line argument
2. You need to provide the path to not-empty folder to generate the [dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) in
3. It worth adding `-f` command-line argument to overwrite existing .jtl results file and dashboard folder if previous results are there
4. You're supposed to be using the latest version of JMeter
5. I think you also need to remove quotation marks at least around `HEAP` variable

Example command line:

```
set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m && C:\jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\script1.jmx -f -l c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\result.jtl -e -o C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\dashboard
```

More information:

- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)
- [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

Comment: 'HEAP' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Got it working, thanks Dmitri after following your comments

Comment: The command doesnt give me any errow now and at the same time my test is not being invoked after i issue the above command with full parameters. Do you understand what could be the reason?